# Create static build of jsc/webkit in order to run on old machine

Tags: build, static, webkit, javascriptcore

I'm doing performance-testing research of different JavaScript interpreters on a cluster of old Fedora machines. node/v8, rhino, and spidermonkey shells all work fine on these machines, but JavaScriptCore (jsc), which I have been able to build on my recent Ubuntu box, is missing a shared library dependency (`error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.44: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`). I'd therefore like to create a static build of jsc with all dependent libraries compiled in so that I can run it on these old machines. I'm wondering if there's a way to create a static build of webkit, or just jsc, so that I can run jsc on these old machines?

Answer (score 1):

Which Webkit are you building ?

Assuming you are just building jscore directly you should be able to pass configure `--enable-static` by using `./configure --enable-static`.

This should override the default of `135    AC_DISABLE_STATIC` in [configure.ac](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/configure.ac).

The build scripts [build-webkit](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Tools/Scripts/build-webkit) and [build-jsc](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Tools/Scripts/build-jsc) don't seem to always forward configure arguments for all build systems and all platforms. I believe Webkit-GTK does.

The steps manually to run using autotools are as follows.

1. `./autogen.sh --prefix=/yourinstallation/prefixhere --enable-static`

   Arguments passed to [autogen.sh](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/autogen.sh) get passed to configure when it calls configure.

   Add necessary configure arguments as you require.
2. `make jsc` followed by `make install` or just the latter. Alternately you could change directory to the `Source/JavaScriptCore` folder and type `make` followed by `make install`.